# Hadoop working Directory

Tags: hadoop

I am attempting to save a file in the main class of a Hadoop application so it can be read later on by the mapper. The file is an encryption key that will be used to encrypt data. My question here is, where will the data end up if I am writing the file to the working directory?

```
public class HadoopIndexProject {

    private static SecretKey generateKey(int size, String Algorithm) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        KeyGenerator keyGen = KeyGenerator.getInstance(Algorithm);
        keyGen.init(size);
        return keyGen.generateKey();
    }

    private static IvParameterSpec generateIV() {
        byte[] b = new byte[16];
        new Random().nextBytes(b);
        return new IvParameterSpec(b);    
    }

    public static void saveKey(SecretKey key, IvParameterSpec IV, String path) throws IOException {
        FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(path);
        //FSDataOutputStream stream = fs.create(new Path(path));
        try {
            stream.write(key.getEncoded());
            stream.write(IV.getIV());
        } finally {
            stream.close();
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     * @throws java.lang.Exception
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // TODO code application logic here
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        //FileSystem fs = FileSystem.getLocal(conf);
        String[] otherArgs = new GenericOptionsParser(conf, args).getRemainingArgs();
        SecretKey KEY;
        IvParameterSpec IV;
        if (otherArgs.length != 2) {
            System.err.println("Usage: Index <in> <out>");
            System.exit(2);
        }
        try {
            if(! new File("key.dat").exists()) {
                KEY = generateKey(128, "AES");
                IV = generateIV();
                saveKey(KEY, IV, "key.dat");
            }
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(HadoopIndexMapper.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        conf.set("mapred.textoutputformat.separator", ":");

        Job job = Job.getInstance(conf);
        job.setJobName("Index creator");
        job.setJarByClass(HadoopIndexProject.class);      
        job.setMapperClass(HadoopIndexMapper.class);
        job.setReducerClass(HadoopIndexReducer.class);

        job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setMapOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(IntArrayWritable.class);

        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(otherArgs[0]) {});
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(otherArgs[1]));

        System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not concept of working directory in HDFS. All relative paths are paths from `/user/<username>`, so your file will be located in `/user/<username>/key.dat`.

But in yarn you have concept of distributed cache, so additional files for your yarn application you can add there using `job.addCacheFile`

Comment: I figured out my mistake here. I was not using the FileSystem instance I created. Now I got the directory you mentioned to be created and I can find my key. The question not is how I can have my mapper and reducer read that key. Also, can you explain the concept of distributed cache?